# python merge data frames

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, stock

i have exported stocks data from metastock to excel because i want to do some work on it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2FK4.png) i exported every stock in an excel file as this pic

i used below code to load the data ,remove the first raw and change the close column header to close + stock sample
and all of that is ok but my problem is in merging all in one table based on date
it always gives me nan as value and i cannot understand the problem

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

files = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Eng\Desktop\out')
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'XLS']
df = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='01/01/1998', end='06/06/2023'), columns=['DATE'])

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, skiprows=[0])
    data.rename(columns = {'CLOSE': Path(f).resolve().stem+'CLOSE'}, inplace = True)
    data.drop(columns=data.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
    data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
    data = data.set_index(['DATE'])
    df = df.join( data)
```

i want to merge all the sheets based on date

Answer (score 0):

i had an error on  `data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")`
instead i wrote `data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")`
and it worked perfectly